# Laravel (Sail): Vite Dev Server not found (404)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, webpack, vite

I am currently switching from webpack to vite.

Current status is, that build commands (yarn production) works for js and css using vite.

However, using the dev server, I receive an 404 message telling me, that the files weren't found - what did I miss?

[image: term]

Below is my code:

vite.config.js

```
export default ({ command }) => ({
    base: command === 'serve' ? '' : '/build/',
    publicDir: 'fake_dir_so_nothing_gets_copied',
    build: {
        manifest: true,
        outDir: 'public/build',
        rollupOptions: {
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
        },
    },
    server: {
        strictPort: true,
        port: 3000
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': '/js',
        }
    }
});
```

helpers.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;

function vite_assets(): HtmlString
{
    $devServerIsRunning = false;

    if (app()->environment('local')) {
        try {
            Http::get("http://localhost:3000");
            $devServerIsRunning = true;
        } catch (Exception) {
        }
    }

    if ($devServerIsRunning) {
        return new HtmlString(<<<HTML
            <script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/@vite/client"></script>
            <script type="module" src="http://localhost:3000/resources/js/app.js"></script>
        HTML);
    }

    $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents(
        public_path('build/manifest.json')
    ), true);

    return new HtmlString(<<<HTML
        <script type="module" src="/build/{$manifest['resources/js/app.js']['file']}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/{$manifest['resources/js/app.js']['css'][0]}">
    HTML);
}
```

so I can finally embed `{{ vite_assets() }}` inside my blade layout

Comment: So the solution was to add an extra port inside the docker-compose.yml ("-3000:3000") and edit my vite.config.js to add the host option (which looks in all networks including dockers 0.0.0.0.) so I can finally see my changes

Comment: ```server: {
        host: true
    }```and ```vite --host 0.0.0.0```

Comment: You didn't stipuled `Docker` in your question - you should edit it as it make no sense as is as the config is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use: https://laravel-vite.dev/ when passing from webpack to vite, it worked perfect for me and took me like less than an hour.

Comment: Im using laravel-vite, latest Laravel9 BUT same issue! endless 404

Comment: @ofumbi - Check that `config.server.hmr.host` is set in `vite.config.js`.

Comment: server: {        hmr: {            host: 'localhost',        },       }